# Firemonkey: How can I detect the X position of a character in a memo

Tags: delphi, text, firemonkey

I'm trying to develop a method that justify my text in a memo/label. But I need to take the X position of a character. Is this possible? If not, how can I justify my texts in firemonkey? I know that this is possible on desktop using an VLC library, but I found nothing for firemonkey.

Comment: See [TTextLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.TextLayout.TTextLayout) if you can work it out. The layout of each line in the memo is accessed by: `layout:= TTextLayout(memo1.Lines.Objects[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything for getting X coords of chars.
You can create array of widths of characters for your font and make method to count absolute x and y of characters, something like this:

```
for y := 0 to Memo.Lines.Count - 1 do
  for x := 0 to Memo.Lines[y].Length - 1 do 
  begin
    AbsoluteX := AbsoluteX + CharWidths[Memo.Lines[y][x]]; 
    AbsoluteY := AbsoluteY + CharHeights[Memo.Lines[y][x]]; 
    // Be careful, for crossplatform using you should use Copy(), not string[n]
  end;
```

For text align you can use this(for label you also have VerTextAlign)

```
Memo.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Trailing; // For right justify
Memo.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Center; // For center justify
Memo.TextAlign := TTextAlign.Leading; // For default left justify
```